# Can apache 2.2 support for Php 5.4? What is minimum supported apache version for php5.4? I am using linux red hat hosting

Tags: web-hosting, php-5.4, apache2.2

Can apache 2.2 support for Php 5.4 and higher? If not what is minimum supported version of apache for the same?